# iphone EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I seem to get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I select a cell in my table view that takes me to a 2nd table view with a lot of these http://pastie.org/906711 could they be the problem if I have 8 of them ?

Heres the backtrace : http://pastie.org/906729

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Is any part of that line 36 of MenuViewController.m?

Comment: Sorry , which line do you mean ?

Comment: Your a genius I was missing an '@' in my array where I was initializing each object. Please post as an answer and I'll select your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comment works nicely